# perl grep fails for strings containing parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

i am trying to grep some string from an array, the grep always fail for string values which contain parentheses.

so for example following fails to find a match in the array, even though it exists:

```
$str='my name is Alpha(beta is old)';

@array=(
'my name is Alpha(beta is old)',
'my name is beta',
'my name is Apple(i am fruit)'
);

$match=grep(/$str/,@array);
```

this fails for all records which have () (i.e. parentheses).

does anyone know how to get around this problem?

thank you.

Comment: [`quotemeta()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis `\( \)` or use [quotemeta()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
$str= quotemeta('my name is Alpha(beta is old)');

@array=(
'my name is Alpha(beta is old)',
'my name is beta',
'my name is Apple(i am fruit)'
);

$match=grep(/$str/,@array);
print $match;
#1
```